# Why so much killing

Tags: deuteronomy, numbers

How did God justify taking over others lands and killing all of other tribes in the process?!  (Numbers, Deuteronomy)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why did God command the Israelites to drive out and kill different nations in Deuteronomy 7](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/63705/why-did-god-command-the-israelites-to-drive-out-and-kill-different-nations-in-de)

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for joining the group and your question.  Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to discover how this site is different from others.

Comment: **This may be a Duplicate** of Christianity SE # 63705 (mentioned by Jason) which would elicit the same answers.  This is an important question since the action in Canaan is used by atheists --and honest inquirers--to doubt the veracity of the inspiration of the Bible., and the Bible's God.

Comment: @ SJ Campbell - See answers given on Question #63705 by Ray Grant, which deal with (1) Judgment Tempered by Mercy, (2) No Conscience, (3) Intermarriage, (4) Diseases.  Keep studying the Bible; it's great for the soul!

Answer (score 1):

‭‭Deuteronomy‬ ‭9:5‭-‬7‬ ‭KJV‬‬

> [5] Not for thy righteousness, or for the uprightness of thine heart,
> dost thou go to possess their land: but for the wickedness of these
> nations the LORD thy God doth drive them out from before thee, and
> that he may perform the word which the LORD sware unto thy fathers,
> Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob. [6] Understand therefore, that the LORD thy
> God giveth thee not this good land to possess it for thy
> righteousness; for thou art a stiffnecked people. [7] Remember, and
> forget not, how thou provokedst the LORD thy God to wrath in the
> wilderness: from the day that thou didst depart out of the land of
> Egypt, until ye came unto this place, ye have been rebellious against
> the LORD.

The Lord was not killing those people because he was giving the land to the Israelites, he was using the Israelites as a tool to wipe away evil in those lands. The people in those lands were doing terrible sins, sacrificing their children to Moloch, performing witchcraft, contacting familiar spirits, beastiality, adultery, worshipping false Gods. God was essentially utilizing a chosen people to stop the sin from exploding out from those areas. Not one man, woman, or child from those cities were allowed to survive or else those practices would continue in some shape or form.

Think of God's wrath as a chemotherapy trying to wipe away cancer (sin) from the land by adopting a scorched earth technique.

What is your solution to a people sacrificing children by throwing them into a pit of fire?

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for joining the group and your answer.  Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to discover how this site is different from others.

Comment: @ Gabriel - Excellent insight, and appropriate metaphor of curing the land! However,  it is best not to ask a Question in the Answer section. It detracts from the Answer...as well as it seeks an opinion, instead of facts. Keep studying the Bible; it's great for the soul!

Answer (score 0):

Consider a single drop of black paint will contaminate an entire bucket of pure white paint with a shade of grey. In a similar vein, the Lord's people are instructed to dress in white, as mentioned in Revelation 3:5; 4:4; and 6:11. However, the Canaanites, who were idol-worshipping tribes, posed a unique challenge. Their very existence would ultimately incite rebellion among the Lord's people against the Lord, even though the Canaanites were a minority.

It is important to note that the command is not limited solely to other tribes. It serves as a fundamental principle applicable even within the Israelite community itself;

Deuteronomy 13:6-11 NIV

> 6 If your very own brother, or your son or daughter, or the wife you love, or your closest friend secretly entices you, saying, “Let us go and worship other gods” (gods that neither you nor your ancestors have known, 7 gods of the peoples around you, whether near or far, from one end of the land to the other), 8 do not yield to them or listen to them. **Show them no pity. Do not spare them or shield them.** 9 **You must certainly put them to death.** Your hand must be the first in putting them to death, and then the hands of all the people. 10 **Stone them to death**, because they tried to turn you away from the Lord your God, who brought you out of Egypt, out of the land of slavery. 11 **Then all Israel will hear and be afraid, and no one among you will do such an evil thing again.**

Demonstrating sympathy and love towards others is a virtue that pleases the Lord. However, it is equally crucial for the Lord's people to set themselves apart from iniquity. Their ultimate goal is to receive God's grace and eternal life. It is important to recognize that even the wicked, regardless of how long they live on earth, will ultimately face the same fate in the lake of fire (as mentioned in Rev 20:15).